# LINQ Query to show if ID exists in list

Tags: c#, sql, linq

```
foreach (var asset in fpt.CouttsPositionSection.ManagedStrategyAssets)
{
var result = FPTStaticDataManagedStrategyAssetlist.Where(e => e.Name == asset.StaticDataManagedStrategyAsset.Name);
if (result == null)
    {
      asset.StaticDataManagedStrategyAsset = FPTStaticDataManagedStrategyAssetlist[random.Next(0, FPTStaticDataManagedStrategyAssetlist.Count())];
    }
}
```

I want to check if **asset.StaticDataManagedStrategyAsset.Name** exists in **FPTStaticDataManagedStrategyAssetlist**. I'm not entirely sure what operator to use?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use [Any](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.linq.enumerable.any%28v=vs.110%29.aspx):

```
if (!FPTStaticDataManagedStrategyAssetlist.Any(e => e.Name == asset.StaticDataManagedStrategyAsset.Name))
{
   //code
}
```

it will return `true` as soon as condition is met.

Also for string comparison you can use `string.Equals(string, string, StringComparision)` if you want more control how to compare strings ([MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/t4411bks.aspx)).

Answer (score 3):

You should change where to use [Enumerable.Any](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.linq.enumerable.any%28v=vs.110%29.aspx).

```
if(!FPTStaticDataManagedStrategyAssetlist.Any(e => e.Name == asset.StaticDataManagedStrategyAsset.Name))
{
    asset.StaticDataManagedStrategyAsset = FPTStaticDataManagedStrategyAssetlist[random.Next(0, FPTStaticDataManagedStrategyAssetlist.Count())];
}
```